# Hardware requirements for playing HD

Tags: requirements, hdvideo

A friend of mine has some HD videos (720p and 1080p), so i would like what are the hardware requirements in order to play them correctly with no slowing-downs ?

my computer is build of :

```
  Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.40GHz
    nvidia GeForce 5200 FX
    768 RAM
```

My friend said that it won't be possible to play the HD videos on my comp because of it's old hardware - is this true ?  And again, what are the minimal hardware setup needed to play HD ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's more to do with your graphics card than anything else. In your case your card supports 1080i, so you should not have any problems.
http://www.nvidia.com/page/pg_20040109440047.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would guess 1080p would be asking too much. Someone else with a low end CPU had success here: [Minimum reasonable system requirements for Windows 7 Media Center](https://superuser.com/questions/70110/minimum-reasonable-system-requirements-for-windows-7-media-center)

If 720p/1080p HD worked on your machine could you post back (and accept an answer)

Answer (score 0):

CPU power also an issue in case of HD. You need at least P4 for your configuration because those celerons were extremely weak. With P4 you will be able to watch at least 720p.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a mention of software in here... its a combination of CPU, GPU and software.  My setup is P4 3.2 GHz, nvidia 9400 GT running linux, and has vdpau support.  I can run 1080p playback with no issues, (plays killasample.avi).  Prior to upgrading my video card, i had a 6000 series nvidia which had no vdpau support in the drivers.  I was only able to play 720p with that combination.